# Finding Invisible Recaptcha Callback Function

Tags: javascript, powershell, recaptcha

I have a Captcha service for Captcha Bypass. The problem is the script works fine on most other sites, but this site does not have a callback function although it does have a callback. So how would I execute the Callback?

Here is my Code:

```js
$CResponse = "uuuhuihhoihoihloi"
$browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = arguments[0];", $CResponse)
$browser.executeScript("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].F.F.callback('arguments[0]');", $CResponse)
```

The error I get is Callback function does not exist.

Please help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it.
I had to add: document.getElementById('captchaform').submit();
So the final code was:

> document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = CResponse;
> document.getElementById("captchaform").submit();

No callback function or statement was needed, although the callback was looking for the submit. Thanks for the 2capctha support and this link https://gist.github.com/2captcha/2ee70fa1130e756e1693a5d4be4d8c70 . There tons of good examples and help on it.